# add xib files to project that has storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, storyboard, xib

I'm iPhone junior, I'm using Xcode 4.3 with iOS5.
I created a huge project using storyboard of iPhone5 and when I tried to publish, the project has been rejected because they told me that it is not run in iPhone4 & iPad3. 
Now, I'm trying to solve this problem and I tried to make it run in iPhone4 emulator in Xcode, but it gives this error:

```
storyboards are unavailable on ios 4.3 and prior
```

and I googled and found that I have to create xib files.

But I haven't an idea how to do this and create Xib files for each viewControllers as there are now (h & m) files only. 
and if I created Xib file, is this will lead to remove the storyboard from the project after I spent a long time building it?
please help me. 
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: That's why I say that every beginner should absolutely begin by making the UI from code.

Comment: I'm pleasnatly surprised that you aggree with me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It probably would've been better to use .xibs in the first place if you were going to target < 5.0.

Essentially yes, you'll have to recreate your storyboard using .xib files. Depending on how you set up your storyboard, this will likely include changes to your code, as well.

<s>You can keep the storyboard as well, though - as far as I can remember, there are two plist options along the lines of "initial XIB" and "initial storyboard" - iOS 5+ will use the latter to load the app.</s>

Comment: Can you please tell me how to  "initial XIB" and "initial storyboard" by steps as I'm new.

Comment: They're simply settings in your .plist file named "Main storyboard file base name" and "Main nib file base name." The former needs to be set if you use a storyboard - so you should already have it - and the latter will be used to load an .xib for iOS <5.0. Of course, you have to create the .xib files first!

Comment: My apologies, you actually can't use both XIBs **and** storyboards in the same project. You will have to recreate your storyboard in XIB files and then set the "main nib file base name" as per my last comment - it's also listed as "Main interface" in the project overview.

Answer (score 0):

select your project in project navigator,select summary tab,and set deployment target to the 5.0 or later(whichever available on your iphone),it may work

Comment: My Deployment target is 5.1, I want to make my project run to old versions not new versions.

Comment: iPhone 4 has iOS5.0 or later,so if you set the deployment target to 5.0,it will work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support the older versions of IOS you must use XIB files not Storyboards.
Storyboards are only for IOS 5 and high versions. We can't use storyboard and xib in same project. You may want to remove StoryBoard and start with XIB Files.

Answer (score 0):

Change your deployment target with compatible versions